# Calculate 90th percentile of F distribution using "rchisq" function in R programming language

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am working on a problem for my Data Analysis class and I have to figure out a way to calculate the 90th percentile of the $F(3,5)$ distribution using the "rchisq" function in R(programming language).

I know that I have to use this formula: $\displaystyle F= \dfrac{rchisq(x,df=3)/3}{rchisq(x,df=5)/5}$.
However, I am not sure what to use for $x$ or how to figure out the 90th percentile.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Look at functions $df,pf,qf,rf$. They provide everything for $F$ distribution including percentage ($pf$).

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the percentile you just have to use quantile(F, 0.9) after defining F as I did above in the question (with n=100000).